# Points of nodes in Spritekit

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, nodes, contains, point

Just to be sure about it, if I have a vector image of a ring and I connect it to a node in xCode SpriteKit with: 
SKTexture *node = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"ring"];
, what will be the part of that node? Is the node itself the rectangle around the ring (and the hole as well) or does it recognise that the ring's point are the only points on the picture so there is nothing around it and inside the ring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define SKTexture, you're just defining the texture for a node.  Make sure you understand the difference.  A texture is just an image that you apply to a node.  Think of a node as a canvas, and a texture is the paint.

I'm saying this because you write SKTexture ***node** = [SKTexture....
which leads me to believe you're creating a node, you aren't.  youre only creating the texture for a node.

Anyway, that texture will be as large as the size of your image.  It will be a rectangle the size of your ring.  If your ring is a perfect circle and has a diameter of 10, your texture will be a perfect square with a width and height of 10.  Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it didn't copy the next line, I will add that texture to a node. And now I see, but is there any way to do what I would like to? Does spriteNodeWithImageNamed do the same "canvas around the image?

Comment: i dont know what you would like to do.  you arent being specific enough.

Comment: basically I want to add this to "touchesBegin" method and if I have a node with a picture I want the program to recognise my touch only if it's on the picture. As I use vector pictures (which don't have default background, so inside and around the "ring" there is nothing) I thought the point of the node will be the point of the image (and not the rectangle around the image). I think I know the answer, but is it possible to do how I imagined?

Comment: When you're detecting touches spritekit is going to be using a square.   Usually the square is tight enough to the image that youre not going to notice youre not exactly touching the edge of a ring.  A phone screen isn't that big anyway.

Comment: :) this was my very first question on stackoverflow, I didn't know it, thank you! :)